Grand Tack Hypothesis and Nice model
The two models describe the evolution of the solar system at different timescales, but both result in the current location of Jupiter. Are they compatible with eachother? Could the Grand Tack be the solar system prequel of the Nice model?

The answer to your two questions is positive: the Grand Tack hypothesis and the Nice model are compatible with each other, since the Grand Tack is supposed to happen before what is described by the Nice model.
According to Kevin Walsh's (one of the 5 authors of the paper (see the arXiV version for easier access if needed) where the Grand Tack hypothesis was proposed) page, the

Grand Tack provides initial conditions for the Nice Model, which is proposed to happen 500 Myr later (around 4 billion years ago)

and also, said in another way:

The Grand Tack models something that happens in the first 5 Myr of the Solar System, while the Nice Model happens 500 Myr later.

